# Publish a PDF copy of the patent

Tags: copyright, websites, pdf

Our patent (US9286268) was issued on March 15, 2016. Can I put a PDF copy of the patent to my server/homepage?

Comment: Better yet: not only you, but *anyone* can :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The patent is a public document which anyone can download for free from the USPTO. You are free to post a copy to your homepage.